# Difference between こぼれる and あふれる

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between the two words `こぼれる` and `あふれる`?

I think for `こぼれる`, the focus is on **improper or bad containment** leading to overflow/spillage.
 And for `あふれる` the focus is on the **abundance** of the object being contained, therefore leading to overflow/spillage.

As an aside, how frequently is the kanji `溢` used for `あふれる` and `こぼれる`?
 I ask this because Google IME suggests `溢れる` for both `あふれる` and `こぼれる`.
 Is `あふれる` usually in kana and `こぼれる` usually `零れる`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your analysis is correct.  As a Christian, `溢れる` is used often in church, the Bible, etc. to describe such as God's overflowing love (`神様の溢れ出る愛`), overflowing joy, etc.  And I usually see it written using the kanji `溢`.

I have never seen `こぼれる` written with `溢`.  The kanji `零` (れい) also means "zero", so it's not hard to see that spilling something might result in an amount of zero leftover.  So this has a more negative connotation than `溢れる`.

Answer (score 5):

- こぼれる is the general term for "spill". It can be due to leakage, overflow, tilt, etc.
- 溢れる specifically means "spill due to overflow", or "full of" without particular mention to spill.